# Ruby On Rails: NameError: uninitialized constant Timezone::Configure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

rails 4.2

rake, version 10.4.2

I am taking over a project from another developer. I was able to checkout the code from Github and I was able to run "bundle install". But then I do:

```
  bundle exec rake db:setup
  rake aborted!
  NameError: uninitialized constant Timezone::Configure
```

This seems to reference something in:

```
  config/application.rb
```

That file looks like:

```
  # Pick the frameworks you want:
  require "active_model/railtie"
  require "active_job/railtie"
  # require "active_record/railtie"
  require "action_controller/railtie"
  require "action_mailer/railtie"
  require "action_view/railtie"
  require "sprockets/railtie"
  require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

  # Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
  # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

  module Invtr
    class Application < Rails::Application
      Timezone::Configure.begin do |c|
        c.username = 'AIzaSyAtf'
        c.google_api_key = 'AIzaSyAtf'
      end

      # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
      # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
      # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

      # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
      # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
      # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

      # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
      # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
      # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    end
  end
```

I have been told that this was working for the previous developer, so I have to assume the problem is with something with my setup. But what else do I need to do? Why is the correct gem not being loaded?

The previous developer had put this line in the Gemfile:

```
  gem 'timezone'
```

And I see:

```
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/timezone-1.1.1
```

So the gem is there.

But somehow it is not being loaded in application.rb.

My Gemfile:

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'turbolinks'
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
  gem 'oauth2'
  gem 'faraday'
  gem 'signet'
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'icalendar'
  gem 'quiet_assets', '~> 1.1'
  gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'
  gem 'bson_ext'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'simple_form'
  gem 'foundation-rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]

  gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
  gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.3.4'

  # CircleCI test metadata formatters
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter', '0.2.2'
  gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
  gem 'geocoder'
  gem 'timezone'
  gem "httpclient"

  group :development do
    # gem "letter_opener"
  end

  group :development, :test do
    gem 'byebug'
    gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
    gem 'spring'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'faker'
  end

  group :test do
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  end
```

Comment: where did he put `gem 'timezone'`? it may have to be _not_ in, e.g., the test group

Comment: posting your gemfile might help

Comment: @ollaollu -- I have now posted my Gemfile

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the version of the `timezone` gem you are using. Since version `1.0.0`, you have to make these changes:
in `config/application.rb` file  instead of using:

```
Timezone::Configure.begin
```

for configuration with Geonames you should use:

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:geonames)
```

and for google:

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:google)
```

Also update your Gemfile:

change `gem 'timezone'` to `gem 'timezone', '~> 1.0'`

So your code would look like:

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:geonames) do |c|
    c.username = 'AIzaSyAtf'
end
```

or

```
Timezone::Lookup.config(:google) do |c|
    c.api_key = 'AIzaSyAtf'
end
```

Ref: 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/timezone

Comment: Thank you for this answer, though you posted a few months after I asked the question. I am no longer working on that project.

Answer (score 0):

Add `require "timezone"` to the file.

Comment: If I add "require timezone" to the config/application.rb and then run "bundle exec rake db:setup" I still get "NameError: uninitialized constant Timezone::Configure". The stacktrace points to this line: "Timezone::Configure.begin do |c|"

Comment: I did that. But that didn't help.